# .htaccess mod_rewrite not interpreting friendly URL in IE (works on FF, Chrome, Safari)

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, internet-explorer

I'm using mod_rewrite on my webpage to allow the proper handling of friendly URLs.  It works perfectly in FF, Chrome, and Safari, yet in IE the friendly urls keep serving me up a 404 error (it's not handling the rewrite properly so it's showing as a 404).

Has anyone had any experience with this?  And if so, how was it resolved?

Note: I have cleared my cache, cookies, and session and also restarted the browser.  I am using IE 9, but have tried IE7 and 8 as well, using the developer tools, with no luck in any IE mode.  Also something to note, is that IE can rewrite some pages, but for others it doesn't work.

**Example**
 A user visits:

```
www.mysite.com/products/99-shoes.html
```

and the server will interpret and serve up the page from here:

```
www.mysite.com/product.php?id_product=99
```

Here is an example of the type of directive I'm using in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Update: Extra Information**
  As requested, I have supplied my RewriteLog below.  The first one is from when I access the page on Chrome (works correctly).  The second one is what outputs when I access the page in IE.  The page in question I am trying to load is:  http://localhost/products-fb/10-loop.html.  I have stripped out some of the repeated characters and timestamps to adhere to StackOverflow's 30k character limit.  If you think I may have removed something important, please let me know and I can upload a .txt file for viewing instead.

Chrome Log Output

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /products-fb/10-loop.html
(1) pass through /products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] add path info postfix: C:/www/products-fb -> C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/products-fb/10-loop.html -> products-fb/10-loop.html
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri 'products-fb/10-loop.html'
(2) [perdir C:/www/] rewrite 'products-fb/10-loop.html' -> '/product-fb.php?id_product=10'
(3) split uri=/product-fb.php?id_product=10 -> uri=/product-fb.php, args=id_product=10
(1) [perdir C:/www/] internal redirect with /product-fb.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /product-fb.php
(1) pass through /product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/product-fb.php -> product-fb.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^page-not-found$' to uri 'product-fb.php'
(1) [perdir C:/www/] pass through C:/www/product-fb.php
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /cart.php
(1) pass through /cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^page-not-found$' to uri 'cart.php'
(1) [perdir C:/www/] pass through C:/www/cart.php
```

IE Log Output

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /page-not-found
(1) pass through /page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/page-not-found -> page-not-found
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^page-not-found$' to uri 'page-not-found'
(2) [perdir C:/www/] rewrite 'page-not-found' -> '/404.php'
(1) [perdir C:/www/] internal redirect with /404.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /404.php
(1) pass through /404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^page-not-found$' to uri '404.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/404.php -> 404.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^address$' to uri '404.php'
(1) [perdir C:/www/] pass through C:/www/404.php
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /cart.php
(1) pass through /cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^api/?(.*)$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^products-fb/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$' to uri 'cart.php'
(3) [perdir C:/www/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/www/cart.php -> cart.php
(3) [perdir C:/www/] applying pattern '^page-not-found$' to uri 'cart.php'
(1) [perdir C:/www/] pass through C:/www/cart.php
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really interesting question.

May I ask you to add the rewritelog and the rewrite error in your question?

### Here are my usual hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

---

May I ask you to add the rewritelog and the rewrite error in your question?

Comment: Thanks Olivier.  I've included the outputs from the log file that was generated by adding that RewriteLog directive to the end of my httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of frustration, the solution was not satisfactory and seems to be some bug in IE9.  I used the developer tools panel and changed the Tools > Change User Agent String from "Default", to "Google Chrome".  Then the page loaded fine.  Once I set the User Agent String back to "Default", the page would still load fine.  I really have no clue what or why it happened because I've never played around with those settings before, but I wanted to post it for anyone else who might suffer from this.